# if else statement in as2

Tags: flash, if-statement, actionscript-2

I have a flash file in witch I"m receiving data from XML document and need when specific word is shown  to load a picture. For example I have:

```
 if (_root.main.ma4.team1.text = "specific text") 
     {
       _root.main.ma4.testo.text = "works";
    }else{
       _root.main.ma4.testo.text = "notworks";
    }
```

So I'm getting "specific text" from the XML file, but right now it's always show me "works" doesn't matter what kind of text i'm getting from the XML. Only shows me notworks when there is no text in the field. So i need to show me "works"only when the specific text is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `==` instead of `=` when comparing :

```
if (_root.main.ma4.team1.text == "specific text") 
     {
        _root.main.ma4.testo.text = "works";
     }
else {
        _root.main.ma4.testo.text = "notworks";
     }
```

and instead of :   `my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[2].firstChild;`

use : `my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[2].nodeValue`

Comment: It's not working again, now the process is just switched, it always show me notworks only when there is no text in the field shows me works. Probably I'm not getting the right path ?

Comment: yes, but now when i have `team1.text=="specText"`  it shows me `notworks` Here is the path from where I'm getting the text from the XML file `_root.main.ma4.team1.text = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[2].firstChild;`

Comment: I'm not getting enything. There is no text shown ? Probably it's not making the connection with the xml file ?

Comment: I've did it in the first time and its not showing me anything, no errors and in the "output"  is nothing too.

Comment: ok, so what to do, because i have `"specific text"` in the XML file and i have the same statement in my as2, basically it's not empty ?

Comment: still the same here is my xml file

Comment: `<game>
        <startdate>2002-05-30 09:00:00</startdate>
         <minute>45</minute>
         <team1>specific text</team1>
          <team2>text</team2>
         <score1>0</score1>
         <score2>0</score2>
         </game>
`

Comment: that should work : `_root.main.ma4.team1.text = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[2].nodeValue;`

Comment: `_root.main.ma4.team1.text = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[2].nodeValue;` with this ive got "null" in the text area.